# Convert string to double in word (vba)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to convert a text in a word document to be a double, so I can do currency formatting on it. I receive this text from a mail merge. How would I create a macro that can receive this text and return it as a number?
I'm unfamiliar with word, and VBA script. What I have made so far is

```c
Function stringToDouble(baseString As String)
    Dim num As Double

    num = Val(baseString)

    stringToDouble = num

End Function
```

I'm not sure how I would call this macro. Because it takes a parameter it does not show up in the macro table. 
I may be completely off on how to convert text to a double in word, but any help is appreciated.
Thanks. Please comment for any clarifications.

Comment: Can you provide an example string?  Are you converting strings that look like "$1,500.99"?

Comment: What does this have to do with Excel?

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  To format a numeric string as currency, all you need is the `Format` function in VBA:  `Format("123456.789", "$#,##0.00")` --> `123,456.79`

Comment: An example string would be a value received from mail merge it is «Service Product View.Total». How do I call that format function on this specific string in a Microsoft word document? Did not mean to tag excel.

Comment: How to call the macro is your main question? You have to tell us more about how it's to be used. For example, does the user select the text then run the macro? Or is this part of another process?

Comment: I would like this macro to automatically run. The user just clicks print invoice, and the invoice is populated from a mail merge. The amounts are unformatted though and seem to be strings. So yes calling a macro with an argument is my main question.

Comment: print invoice is a button on a web application.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a macro for this!!! All you need do is learn how to use formatting switches in Word fields.

To control number & currency formatting in Word, add a numeric picture switch to the mergefield. To do this:

- select the mergefield;
- press Shift-F9 to reveal the field coding. It should look something like {MERGEFIELD MyData};
- edit the field so that you get {MERGEFIELD MyData # $,0.00} (or whatever other numeric format you prefer - see below);
- position the cursor anywhere in this field and press F9 to update it.

**Note 1:** The '# $,0.00' in the field is referred to as a numeric picture switch. Other possibilities include:

- # 0 for rounded whole numbers
- # ,0 for rounded whole numbers with a thousands separator
- # ,0.00 for numbers accurate to two decimal places, with a thousands separator
- # $,0 for rounded whole dollars with a thousands separator
- # "$,0.00;($,0.00);'-'" for currency, with brackets around negative numbers and a hyphen for 0 values

**Note 2:** The precision of the displayed value is controlled by the '0.00'. You can use anything from '0' to '0.000000000000000'.
If you use a final ';' in the formatting switch with nothing following, (eg # "$,0.00;($,0.00);") zero values will be suppressed. Note that this suppresses 0s resulting from empty fields and from fields containing 0s.

**Note 3:** If you use a decimal tab or right-aligned tab to align the values, wrap the switch in quotes (i.e. # "$,0.00") and insert a tab into the field code after the $ sign, you can have the values output with the decimal alignment occurring after the $ sign.

For more Mailmerge Tips & Tricks, see: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the number to a `Double` data type then try this:

```
Function StringToDouble(ByVal baseString As String) As Double
    StringToDouble = VBA.CDbl(baseString)
End Function
```

If you're only concerned about formatting currency, convert the string to the `Currency` data type like this:

```
Function StringToCurrency(ByVal baseString As String) As Currency
    StringToCurrency = VBA.CCur(baseString)
End Function
```

You will still need to format the number but both functions give you a number that can be formatted.

Here's an example that also gives you a string formatted as USD (e.g. $4,999.75).  It requires the `StringToCurrency` function above.

```
Sub test()
    Dim stringNum As String
    stringNum = "4,999.754501"
    Debug.Print "stringNum=" & stringNum                ' outputs 4,999.754501

    Dim currencyNum As Currency
    currencyNum = StringToCurrency(stringNum)           ' outputs 4999.7545
    Debug.Print "currencyNum=" & currencyNum

    Dim formattedString As String
    formattedString = Format$(currencyNum, "$#,##0.00")
    Debug.Print "formattedString=" & formattedString    ' outputs $4,999.75
End Sub
```

Comment: Currency in not a double, it is an 64 bit integer counting 10,000th of a dollar/rupee. From VBA Language Spec - __Currency  Numbers with 4 fractional decimal digits in the range  -922,337,203,685,477.5808 to  +922,337,203,685,477.5807  
64-bit signed binary two’s complement integer  implicitly scaled by 10-4__

Comment: Note to internationalization: `CCur` conversion from a given string (instead from a double) uses regional language settings regarding decimal points which may give unwanted results e.g. in most central European countries ("," instead of a decimal point ".")

Comment: How would I get stringNum to be dynamic changing on the text in the word document? I receive my amount/num from a mailmerge field.

Comment: Is the source an Excel file?  Do you have the option of changing the data on the source?